# multiple rows to an array

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this script

```
for row in c:
    res = subprocess.Popen('bgpq3 -4 {} -m 24 -l {}'.format(row[5],row[2]), shell=True, universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = res.communicate()
    for line in stdout.split('\n')[1:10]:
          print(line)
```

which results:

```
ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.6.0/23
ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.8.0/24
ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.9.0/24
ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.10.0/24
```

how can i put these lists to one array?
something like this or a better way that will be easier!

```
{ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.10.0/24,ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.8.0/24,ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.9.0/24,ip prefix-list 2603 permit 2.16.10.0/24}
```

And also how can i query them at the next time? like the reverse way to get multiple rows!

I used this but get multiple rows with multiple arrays

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO newpeers (prefix) VALUES(ARRAY['{}'])ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING".format(line))
```

Comment: postgres or mysql?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  If this is Postgres, why do I see `MySQL` tag on your question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I can understand the problem correctly.
first we need python list like **lines**

```
for row in c:
    res = subprocess.Popen('bgpq3 -4 {} -m 24 -l {}'.format(row[5],row[2]), shell=True, universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = res.communicate()
    lines = []
    for line in stdout.split('\n')[1:10]:
        print(line)
        lines.append(line)
```

And when inserting we use;

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO newpeers (prefix) VALUES (%s)", (lines,))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the the result is not one row but seprated rows with duplicates